# Where has my LIKE button gone?

Tags: facebook, button, like

My LIKE button was working for quite some time.  It did have an issue whereby it would not show up on the initial pageload, but it did show upon refresh.  Weird, but not a deal breaker.

Now, the button is completely gone.  I've tried the linter and it is now coming back with an error of "*There were problems uploading "http://www.getitincode.com/images/siteIcon.png" on behalf of your Open Graph page. Here is the full error message our photo server reported: "General Failure: Picture could not be uploaded."*"  Nothing has changed at all on my end and, in fact, the site is able to coast on auto-pilot.

Any ideas?

The URL in question is www.getitincode.com -- and, if you run the linter and access the graph link at the bottom, you'll find that the page has indeed been shared/liked previously.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

John

Comment: Did you check permissions?

Comment: It is working for me too. Could there have been a timeout when you tested? Check again.

Answer (score 1):

Your like button is appearing for me.